# First and last objects in rails collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my application I have a "Students" partial, that passes a collection of @students to a "student" partial. These are eventually displayed on my index page as images of students. When a user clicks on an image, I'm poping up a box with the student's photo and some text. Now, I have a previous/next button that allows users to cycle through the students. I implemented the cycling w/out a plugin...just a simple ajax call to load the next/previous object. My problem is that I cannot detect when I'm at the last (or first) record. I need a way to probably set a url parameter on the first and last objects. So It would look like this: www.mysite.com/students/15?last=true

I couldn't find a clean way to do this. I'm also not sure if I'm thinking about this the right way. Should I be attaching url parameters? Or should I somehow modify the object to add additional attributes after retrieving them from the model?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

Just wanted to make this a little clearer.
When I pop up the students lightbox, I have 2 links: *previous* (linking to the previous record) and *next* linking to the next record. I'm using the jquery $.load method to make an ajax request and load in the data I want, into a div in my lightbox, whenever I click previous or next.

$('previous').click(
$('mydiv').load('url of previous student');
);

I get the 'url of previous/next student' by walking the dom tree on initial pop up. I store these so I can refer to them again.

My problem is that I cannot tell when I'm at the first student in the list or the last. I need to know this so I can disable the prev/next button. I'm thinking I can either do this through rails/ruby or through javascript. Initially, I thought that by adding a url parameter on the link or the previous/next student (to indicate whether they were first or last), then I could detect this in rails and do a simple if/else to disable the links. But I got stuck at trying to do this with the way I'm referring to the partials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ehm, I do it with my way for inspiration,maybe help you:
Student/index
Classic index file with ajax loading list, will_paginate and code which I wrote above. Every student have image with link, link has href something like /student/4 and remote: true.

student show controller

```
@student = Student.find(params[:id])
```

student show js file
classic js render "student"

student _student.html.erb
your view and two view helper: prev_help(params[:id]) and next_help(params[:id])

helpers:

```
def prev_help(id)
    @student = Student.find(id - 1)
    link_to("Prev". @student )  if @student.nil?        
end

def next_help(id)
    @student = Student.find(id + 1)
    link_to("Prev". @student )  if @student.nil?        
end
```

I don't have time now, but If this solution will not help you, you can write me tomorrow and I'll create sample app to test my solution and colaborate it with you.

Comment: Hey @quatermain, I really appreciate this help. I'll try this out and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need last page, or last student from @students?
I use gem will_paginate for listing of pages and simple JS "ajax" for refresh next page. You can use this gem and set objects per page to 1, for example:

```
@students = Student.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 1, :page => params[:page])
```

Example "ajax" students/index.js:

```
$('tbody').append('<%= j render(@students) %>');
<% if @students.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@students) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

coffescript to activate it:

```
if $('.pagination').length
        $(window).scroll ->
          url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
          if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 230
            $('.pagination').text("Načítavam...")
            $.getScript(url)
        $(window).scroll()
```

I learn it from my Bible ;-) [RailsCasts - Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I think I probably didn't explain clearly enough. I've edited the description above.

Comment: You can use will paginate for it. Gem 'will_paginate' test your current page and show/hide next page link. If you can write your own code, I think you must test ID, if student.id == Student.last.id hide next page link.

Comment: So in this case 'Student' is an array right? But my problem is that I'm using a partial that sends a collection to another partial which does the rendering. So in that second partial, I don't have access to the collection anymore, so I can't test the full collection to figure out which record I'm at. I'm now thinking I might need to add a virtual attribute on the first/last records, but this seems like over-kill

Comment: sorry, it's too long for comment